# Setting the max file size of the file you save strings to in localfolder winRT

Tags: c#, logging, windows-8, windows-runtime

does anyone know if it is possible to set a maximum file size for a file i create in my Applications Localfolder (for WinRT apps). At this point i make a StorageFile like this:

```
private StorageFile m_StorageFile = null;

m_StorageFile = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFileAsync("Myfile.log",
                                                                              CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
```

but i want the file inside the localfolder to have a max size of let's say 10MB. So when it get bigger it should either clear old entry's or clear itself.

i have found numerous answers conserning the max size you can write to the localfolder files but none that describe how to set the max file for the file inside the localfolder.

i need this because i am trying to implement logging into my application, i used to be able to set this in the web.config file like this:

```
<maximumFileSize value="10MB" />
```

using Log4Net but this has not yet been updated to .Net framework 4.5 thats why i followed this tutorial where they give an alternative but i couldn't find anything about max file size, link to tutorial

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Logging-Sample-for-Windows-0b9dffd7

Comment: Can't you do it yourself in your app? Append if the size is less than 10 MB, clear if it gets bigger and then append?

Comment: But the problem is i need a way to let the application see for itself that the file is larger than 10MB so the user would never have to go to the file location to check it. And after reading a bit on appending i think this is something to add lines to a file, but i havent seen anything with it that would check the file size.

Comment: application itself can access the file, get the length of the stream (meaning - get the size) and act appropriately, and do it all *without* user interaction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking up what @Igor left as a comment i came up with a solution for my problem using this code:

```
IRandomAccessStream sessionRandomAccessFile1 = await this.m_StorageFile1.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);
                IRandomAccessStream sessionRandomAccessFile2 = await this.m_StorageFile2.OpenAsync(FileAccessMode.Read);

                if (sessionRandomAccessFile1.Size == 0)
                {
                    await FileIO.AppendLinesAsync(m_StorageFile1, lines);
                }
                else if (sessionRandomAccessFile1.Size < 5000000)
                {
                    if (sessionRandomAccessFile1.Size > 4999900 )
                    {
                        await m_StorageFile2.DeleteAsync();
                        AssignLocalFile();
                    }
                    await FileIO.AppendLinesAsync(m_StorageFile1, lines);

                }
                else if (sessionRandomAccessFile2.Size < 5000000)
                {
                    if (sessionRandomAccessFile1.Size > 5000000 && sessionRandomAccessFile2.Size > 4999900)
                    {
                        await m_StorageFile1.DeleteAsync();
                        AssignLocalFile();
                    }
                    await FileIO.AppendLinesAsync(m_StorageFile2, lines);

                }
```

in the method assignlocalfile i just create new files after deleting them:

```
 private async void AssignLocalFile()
    {
        m_StorageFolder = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.CreateFolderAsync("VakantieApplicatie", CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        m_StorageFile1 = await m_StorageFolder.CreateFileAsync(m_Name.Replace(" ", "_") + "1.log",
                                                                                CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
        m_StorageFile2 = await m_StorageFolder.CreateFileAsync(m_Name.Replace(" ", "_") + "2.log",
                                                                                CreationCollisionOption.OpenIfExists);
    }
```

this way i'll have a max total size of 10MB and when one file of 5MB is full it will switch to the other without deleting the previous because you might need it when you search for an error(in case of logging), when the other 5 MB is full it will clear the first and start writing there again because after 5 MB of error logging i think you won't be needing that data anymore.